# ogr2ogr OSM polygon layer export from PostGIS to SpatiaLite has no CRS

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I used ogr2ogr to export osm layers from PostGIS to SpatiaLite using this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=yes ./mapfile/psql_polygon.sqlite PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=gis user=postgres password=123" "planet_osm_xxx"
```

(xxx here is different for different table)

It goes well for all layers "planet_osm_point, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_polygon and planet_osm_roads". i.e. no errors.

However, with QGIS, all layers can be viewed except **planet_osm_polygon** where it says "This is not a spatial table" (missing CRS). Someone suggested to use below (in PostGIS) then export.

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_polygon ALTER COLUMN way TYPE geometry(Geometry, 3857) USING ST_SetSRID(way,3857);
```

But did not work either.

Does **planet_osm_polygon** require special treatment during export or need further processing?

1. Adding **-a_srs epsg:3857** to ogr2ogr as suggested by [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) did not help.
2. QGIS DB Manager reported "There is no entry in geometry_columns" for this layer on PostGIS side, other layers don't. So, I did "SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('planet_osm_polygon'::regclass);" in PostGIS from [this blog](http://movingspatial.blogspot.com/2013/01/postgis-15-batch-populate-geometry.html). QGIS DOES show the layer BUT there is alot of missing polygons (comapred PostGIS to sptialite) although row count is the same.

Comment: If planet_osm_polygon is actually in EPSG:4326 in PostGIS but for some reason it is not registered so into the metadata, you can just add `-a_srs epsg:4326` into you ogr2ogr command.

Comment: I did this (added -a_srs epsg:3857 ... on command line) but did not work. Still QGIS shows no CRS.

Comment: Have you checked the data on PostGIS side? Can you add the table into QGIS directly from PostGIS?

Comment: I checked the planet_osm_polygon table in PostGIS using QGIS DB Manager, DB manager reported "There is no entry in geometry_columns". Other tables do not have this note.

Comment: i did "SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('planet_osm_polygon'::regclass);" on PostGIS  side as suggested in "http://movingspatial.blogspot.com/2013/01/postgis-15-batch-populate-geometry.html" side and re-export. QGIS now displays the layer in spatialite BUT the layer is not identical to that of PostGIS. too many missing polygons.

Comment: Open both the PostGIS table and SpatiaLite table into QGIS and identify a few features that are present in PostGIS but not in SpatiaLite. Try to find what is special for the features which were not copied into SpatiaLite.

Comment: @user30184, thanks for the hint. I checked a couple of missing features and found present in both. However, the export did not keep the record order and, hence, missing features were actually covered by other polygons.
Now, polygon layers are identical once i made the polygons transparent.

Comment: @user30184, you may post your comment as answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason osm2pgsql has created the planet_osm_polygon table without making the corresponding entry into the "geometry_columns" metadata table right. By the osm2pgsql manual https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#geometry-processing that should not happen. However, if all the other tables has been created as EPSG:3857 then "planet_osm_polygon" is using the same because the `-projection` parameter in osm2pgsql affects all tables and it can be overridden for a single table only by using special flex output configuration.

The metadata in the geometry_columns table can be fixed with the PostGIS function Populate_Geometry_Columns https://postgis.net/docs/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html and then also the exported SpatiaLite table should be created with the right CRS.

If you are using the most recent version of osm2pgsql and you can repeat the issue about incorrect CRS metadata of the polygon table I suggest to report it to the osm2pgsql project https://osm2pgsql.org/support/.